# linux install without yum or gcc

Tags: installation, yum, linux, lamp

Hulo All, Linux newb here.  I just ssh'ed into my first shiny new CentOS virtual server to install a LAMP stack.  No yum, so I had to install yum.  Yum needs gettext, so it got gettext.  Gettext ./configure fails because gcc's not installed.  All the directions I've found so far indicate that I should use yum to install GCC.  Am I missing something here?

Apparently I got what I paid for when I asked for the minimal service.  What's the approach here for getting things on track so that I can follow basic LAMP installation instructions?

Links to web pages are gladly accepted.

UPDATE: `cat /etc/issue` replies:
`CentOS release 5.3 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m`

But [this site](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BrokenVserver) says that my VServer can't be CentOS if yum is missing.  It might be a Plesk VServer.

Comment: Are you sure yum isn't there and just not in your path? I'd think you'd have to try pretty hard to install CentOS without it...

Comment: Nope... no yum.  find / -name "yum" returns the directory where I wgetted it earlier.  I didn't install CentOS.  The virtual server came that way.  Maybe they delete it for you so you have to ask for tech support :-(

Comment: @John What does your $PATH variable look like?

Comment: //sbin://bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

Comment: Yum absent from the system?  If you have a disk of the CentOS you are dealing with, try installing the rpms instead of building from the sources.  Also, try asking at serverfault or superuser where there could be more people tuned to answer things like this.

Comment: you either need 1. a package manager (yumm), or 2. gcc, or 3. your money back! Without one or the other you can't get anywhere. I would get some server tech support. But here are some gcc binaries: http://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html

Comment: check if you have rpm in your path, if yes then use rpm versions of packages, that's hell faster

Comment: possible duplicate of [linux install without yum or gcc](http://serverfault.com/questions/203245/linux-install-without-yum-or-gcc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CentOS people [have a solution for that](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BrokenVserver).

Comment: Yeah... that's what I've been reading.  What do I do?  Call the provider and tell them they gave me a broken server and I'm refusing to pay?

Comment: Did you read section 4?

Comment: Sorry to take so much time to get back.  Yes, sadly your post was the most helpful thing out there.  There are apparently a lot of bad hosting solutions that give you fake or cripples CertOS VPSs so that you'll pay for support.  After the very rough night that I wrote this question, I got rid of my VPS (along with the $50 that I had invested in getting it going) and soon thereafter purchased a Linode.com VPS.  In literally 15 minutes I had accomplished what I couldn't accomplish with the VPS above over the course of 4 miserable days.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be trying to build things from source for this environment (I mean, you can if you want to, it won't hurt, but there are easier solutions available).  Grab the necessary packages from CentOS, and install them using the "rpm" command.  If the "rpm" command isn't available, either, it suggests that your hosting provider *really* doesn't want you installing packages in your virtual server.  There may or may not be a good reason for this, and you should probably follow up with your provider before spending too much time on this problem.

You can find CentOS 5.3 packages here:

- http://vault.centos.org/5.3/

You really want to get yum installed, and then use yum to install everything else.

Answer (score 1):

The CentOS people [have a solution for that](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/BrokenVserver).

Comment: Ok... so you found me on all sites.

Comment: Sadly, this answer was the correct answer.  As the linked document states, I was given a crippled CentOS server and required to pay extra tech support fees to make it not crippled or otherwise eat the setup fees and get a server that actually works.  I chose the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your CENTOS DVD for GCC or check for the below URL for GCC RPM.

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/5244776/dir//com/gcc-3.2.3-59.i386.rpm.html
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=gcc&srodzaj=3

CentOS ISO and Mirror files

http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=15

Refer to below URL for LAMP installation instruction on CENTOS

http://wiki.vpslink.com/HOWTO:_CentOS_5_setup_for_LAMP_and_ISPconfig

Comment: Installing random RPMs off the Internet is certainly cause for concern. Great link for LAMP on CentOS, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check this for the RPM source:

[HERE](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/13944119/dir/centos_5/com/gcc-4.1.2-48.el5.x86_64.rpm.html)

It will tell you where to get it, what it depends on, and where to get those.

But I tend to think that something is  messed up with your installation if "yum" isn't there and working.